# Why is the index on my valueformatter starting at -1?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

When I use "**xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);**" my ValueFormatter index starts at -1 for some reason and my code errs out with an indexOutOfBounds error.

comment the line of code and the chart works as normal.  Uncomment the line of code and I always get an IndexOutofBounds err on my String array: dateTimes.

Looking at the data in the Watch window always shows it starting at index 0, as it should.

```java
private static void AddxAxisLabels(){
        //set xAxis labels
        ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                /* a breakpoint here reveals value= -1 
                  when that last line of code below is uncommented. */
                return dateTimes[(int) value];
            }
        };


        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
//        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    }
```

It is a groupedBarChart.  Could it have something to do with this line of code?

```java
        //perform the "explicit" grouping of systolic/diastolic
        chart.groupBars(0f, .06f, .01f);
```

I set my 'fromX' to 0f instead of the first date in my dateTimes String array because there are multiple entries for the first recorded date. Example:

```java
String[] dateTimes = ["6/27/2017 3:12 PM", "6/27/2017 3:42 PM", "6/28/2017 12:12 PM"].
```

Comment: As i see it, groupBars() is shifting the values X-Pos. Did you find a solution for this, to format the x-Axis-Labels correctly after grouping?

Comment: No, didn't find a solution.  I just used a different chart.

Comment: What worked for me is: You shouldn't get your dateTimes from an array but rather save your Data with timeStamps as xValue, you can convert the timestamp from milliseconds to minutes, so your chart won't be slow. And in your formatter, you get the xValue, convert it back to a valid millis-timeStamp and get the formatted Date with Calendar and Dateformatter or JodaTime. cheers

Comment: Thanks Coding John, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: let me know if it worked. If not i can provide additional info :) Happy Coding